# env: coffee: No such file or directory

Tags: spacemacs, osx

I am try spacemacs. It can correctly recognise a coffee script and start coffeescript mode. However when I try to run coffee REPL, it shows this error:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have the `coffee` program installed and is it in your `PATH`?  If so, you might simply be hitting the old problem of env-vars (i.e. your Emacs did not inherit the PATH config that you set in your shell config, because it was not started from a shell)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

```
  brew install coffeescript
```

to install a coffee script runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You need first to install the **coffee** executable.

From [here](http://coffeescript.org/), you can install it with:

```
npm install -g coffeescript
```